# How can I fix the if loop if thirdName does not have input to take in?

Tags: java

This is the question I am trying to solve.

Format and output the name as shown below:

lastInitial., firstName middleInitial.

If no middle name was provided, format and output the name as shown below:

lastInitial., firstName

So far this is the code I used:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);       
      /* Type your code here. */
      
      String firstName = scnr.next();
      String secondName = scnr.next();
      String thirdName = scnr.nextLine();
      
      if(thirdName.equals(" ")){
         System.out.println(secondName.charAt(0) + "., " + firstName);
      }
      else {
         System.out.println(thirdName.charAt(1) + "., " + firstName + " " + secondName.charAt(0) + ".");  
      }
     
   }
}
```

If the scanner has a white space after the second world the program works, but if there is no white space I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at LabProgram.main(LabProgram.java:10).
```

I have tried to edit the code by changing if to say  `if(thirdName.equals(null)){ System.out.println(secondName.charAt(0) + "., " + firstName); }`
and still got the same error.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: Then maybe `Scanner` is not the right tool for this.

Comment: thirdName.equals(null) -> can you imagine what would happen in the scenario's where you believe this to be true?

Comment: The question is using Scanner to give multiple names, so I have to use it to solve the problem.

Comment: @Stultuske my mistake that was my try at getting the code to still run I updated the question to show I used white space first.

Comment: read the entire line as one String, use the split method, check how many elements there are, and start from there

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks this finally got everything to run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trim() method to remove leading and trailing spaces from thirdName, and use the isEmpty() method to check if the string is empty. This way, your program should work correctly regardless of whether there are spaces. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
   public class LabProgram {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);       
         String firstName = scnr.next();
         String secondName = scnr.next();
         String thirdName = scnr.nextLine().trim();  // Use trim to remove leading and trailing whitespaces
  
  if(thirdName.isEmpty()) {
     System.out.println(secondName.charAt(0) + "., " + firstName);
  }
  else {
     System.out.println(thirdName.charAt(0) + "., " + firstName + " " + secondName.charAt(0) + ".");  
  }
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work it out by using the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);       
      /* Type your code here. */
  
      String name = scnr.nextLine();
      String firstName;
      String secondName;
      String thirdName;
  
      int firstSpace = name.indexOf(" ");
      firstName = name.substring(0, firstSpace);

      int secondSpace = name.indexOf(" ", firstSpace + 1);
  
      if (secondSpace < 0) { 
         thirdName = name.substring(firstSpace + 1);
         System.out.println(thirdName.charAt(0) + "., " + firstName);
      }
      else {
         secondName = name.substring(firstSpace, secondSpace);
         thirdName = name.substring(secondSpace + 1);
         System.out.println(thirdName.charAt(0) + "., " + firstName + " " + secondName.charAt(1) + ".");
      }  
   }
}
```

EDIT:
An alternative solution (after code review):

```
String line = scnr.nextLine();
String[] names = line.split();
String thirdName = names.length > 2 ? " " + names[2] : "";
System.out.printf("%s., %s%s%n", names[0], names[1], thirdName);
```

Comment: You may want to use `String#split` rather than the `charAt` you're using. I edited your answer to include that.

Comment: @daniu Why exactly? How does the String#split work better than charAt.

Comment: there's no real functional difference, but why reinvent the wheel if the function already exists? It's also shorter and makes the checks easier to both write and - more importantly - read.